# Prove that f(z) = 1/2(z + 1/z) is injective in V = {z in C : Im(z) > 0}

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm struggling to prove that f(z) is an injective function with domain V where V = {z $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : Im(z) > 0}.

Up until now, I suppose that theres 2 distinct points in V a and b where f(a) = f(b) and I'm trying to prove by contradiction that a = b. But instead of proving the injectivity, I end up proving surjectivity.

Here's what I have:

$\frac{a^2 + 1}{a} = \frac{b^2 + 1}{b}$

$a^2b + b = ab^2 + a$

$a(ab - 1) + b(1 - ab) = 0$

But that ends up being a proof for surjectivity since if b = 1/a, then f(a) = f(b). I'm not sure how else I could prove injectivity for this function.

Comment: *Hint:* $a(ab - 1) + b(1 - ab) = (a-b)(ab-1)$.

Comment: Well check that if there any $a$ and $b$ in the domain such that $\frac{1}{a}=b$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. From $a(ab-1)+b(1-ab)=0$, you get
$$(a-b)(ab-1)=0 $$
A product is $0$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$. So either $a=b$ (and we are done), or: $ab=1$. Now recall that $a,b\in V$, i.e., $\operatorname{Im} a>0$ and $\operatorname{Im} b>0$. Do you know how to find $b=\frac1a$ if $a=x+iy$?

Comment: Thanks for the help! If b = 1/a and Im(a) > 0, then Im(b) < 0 since 1/a = x - iy/x^2 + b^2 right?!

Answer (score 0):

They have mentioned the imaginary part of $z$ is positive. Like you mentioned, if $a = \frac{1}{b}$ then $f(a) = f(b)$. Assume $a = x + iy  (y > 0)$. Then, that implies $b$ is $\frac{1}{x+iy}$, which can be written as $b = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$ which has as negative imaginary part. So it is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to solve my problem!